# How can i use MPI_Testany and MPI_Irecv to get only the first irecv that will arrive?

Tags: c, mpi, nonblocking, openmpi

In c in "mpi.h", i think it will be something like

```
MPI_Request mpireq[2];
MPI_Status mpistat;
int temp, index, flag;
MPI_Irecv(temp, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpireq[0]);
MPI_Irecv(temp, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpireq[1]);
MPI_Testany(2, mpireq, &index, &flag, &mpistat);
```

but i think Testany is a non-blocking so i don't know how to use flag and index
i propose something like but i don't if this is going to work.

```
if(flag){
  printf("someone came\n");
  if (index == 0){do something}
  else{do something else}
} else
  printf("No one is here yet");
```

Comment: What is `flag` ? What is *something* ? does *something* have side effects? Also: your automatic variables are uninitialised.

Comment: There is no global order in MPI, so even if I do not know what you have in mind by "the first irecv that will arrive" you are probably getting it wrong. `MPI_Testany()` is non blocking, are you looking for the blocking version (`MPI_Waitany()`)? `flag` is true if a message has been received, and then `index` is the index in the requests array (in `mpireq` here) that has matched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this and it seems to work

```
MPI_Irecv
MPI_Irecv
MPI_Testany
while(!flag)
  MPI_Testany();
if(flag)
  capture Irecv that comes first;
```